# Update table with query gives me this error: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgresql

I am new on Postgresql

I have the table "admins_polygons" where I have the column "_geometry" which has WKT values on it and I need to convert that WKT to geometry values on other column from the same table.

I already created the geometry column but when I try to use UPDATE to fill the rows with a CAST it gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

This is my code so far

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('admins_polygons', 'polygons', 4326, 'POLYGON', 2)

SELECT admins_polygons._geometry
FROM admins_polygons

SELECT CAST (admins_polygons._geometry AS GEOMETRY)
FROM admins_polygons

UPDATE admins_polygons SET 
polygons = (SELECT CAST (admins_polygons._geometry AS GEOMETRY)
FROM admins_polygons)
```

Comment: Error explains it. The `(SELECT ...)` can only return one row to the `UPDATE`. See [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) **EXAMPLES** section for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the subquery further, preferably with a uniquely-constrained column, such that it only returns a single record.

Thankfully, you've already created this with such a key, namely the srid of the geometry column:

```
UPDATE admins_polygons SET 
    polygons = 
        (SELECT CAST(admins_polygons._geometry AS GEOMETRY) 
            FROM admins_polygons WHERE srid = 4326) WHERE srid = 4326 ;
```

or, equivalently

```
UPDATE admins_polygons SET 
    polygons = CAST(admins_polygons._geometry AS GEOMETRY)
WHERE srid = 4326 ;
```

which ought to yield the single-row result you're looking for for use in the SET assignment.

Note you'll likely want to include the last WHERE condition as well if you only want this one record to be updated.